# accurate triggering on scroll

Tags: javascript, onscroll

I have a simple on scroll event, that checks when a scroll amount has been reached. The problem I have is often it does not get fired.

```
var viewH = document.documentElement.clientHeight
var siteMargin = 40
var slideHeight = viewH * 0.8 - siteMargin
var slideCnt = 1
var slidesArr = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
var lastSlide = 0; 

document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

var doc = document.documentElement;
var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);

var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
if (st > lastScrollTop) {
     // scroll down
    if (top == slideHeight * slideCnt) {
       // do something
    }
} else {
    // scrolling up
}
lastScrollTop = st;
}, false);
```

I have tried changing to:

```
 if (top >= slideHeight * slideCnt) {
   // do something
   }
```

but then it fires multiple times...

demo here: https://codepen.io/garethj/pen/QOzmeO?editors=1010

Comment: `if (hasNotFired && condition)` So set something that says it has run.